# Snap-Firefox does not open Dropbox link

Tags: firefox, 22.04, snap, dropbox

In Ubuntu 22.04 I installed Firefox (105.0b1) with Snap. I use Dropbox (v155.4.5493). If I want to "Launch Dropbox Website" in the Dropbox application then Firefox should open the Dropbox site.
But instead it tells me "File not found" and in the middle of the page it shows "Firefox can’t find the file at /tmp/dbxlcr7lvma8.html#8f92595a3bd48760306e963b305d58ddf0958877117f770ffaa4d8960c2f4f1bd3a6b6bf3378acb08d7178.".

**Workaround:** Install Firefox without snap then it works. But this solution has other disadvantages.

So. Who's problem is that? Ubuntu? Firefox? Snap or Dropbox? Who is going to fix it? It worked so nicely in Ubuntu 20.04 without the snap-Firefox.

Comment: Clearly it is 'snap'.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, the problem is snap. The technology is recent and on the technical side, things work differently than before. This also results in breakage of some use cases. These may get fixed or worked around, or may mandate workflow changes.

Comment: Workflow changes are more likely. Otherwise it would have to run unconfined in order to access /tmp

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem that already been identified.

The best work round I have found is to use the URL to launch your `Dropbox`Home page from within Firefox (perhaps saved as a Bookmark) as opposed to the drop down menu option.

`https://www.dropbox.com/h`